# How to use .net System.Diagnostics::Process OnExited C++?

Tags: .net, events, event-handling, c++-cli

Can anyone please give an example how to use the OnExited event in C++, see link form msdn which one I'm referring to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.onexited.aspx . I am really confused with this C++/CLI. I am trying to delete a file after the process exited. I got it working in C# but prefer C++ so it can be easier to be wrapped for JNI.

Comment: You're going to load the JVM and the CLR into the same process? Scary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not *really* sure what you want, so here's a literal translation of the code on the page you linked to from C# to C++/CLI:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

ref class MyProcess : public Process
{
public:
    void Stop()
    {
        this->CloseMainWindow();
        this->Close();
        OnExited();
    } 
};

void myProcess_HasExited(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Process has exited.");
}

int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    MyProcess^ p = gcnew MyProcess();
    p->StartInfo->FileName = L"notepad.exe";
    p->EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p->Exited += gcnew EventHandler(myProcess_HasExited);
    p->Start();
    p->WaitForInputIdle();
    p->Stop();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I cant get it to complile. Gettings errors. 1>  test2.cpp
1>test2.cpp(20): error C2628: 'MyProcess' followed by 'void' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
1>test2.cpp(30): error C3352: 'myProcess_HasExited' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========